# There are 2 states for a single binary random variable, how about multinoulli distributions?

Tags: probability

section 3.9 of the "Deep Learning Book" [Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville. Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) says

> The Bernoulli and multinoulli distributions are sufficient to describe any distribution over their domain. This is because they model discrete variables for which
>   it is feasible to simply enumerate all of the states.

There are 2 states for a single binary random variable, namely, {0,1}. how about multinoulli distributions?

Answer (score 1):

Multinoulli random variable takes any finite set of real values, for example $\{-0.5, 1.2, 3.5\}$. Bernoulli random variable is a particular case of multinoulli random variable.